# Support for ternary operator in Solr FunctionQuery

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to run a solr search where I need to sort on a combination of fields e.g,

```
q=*:*&sort=endtime != null ? endtime : starttime - 100;
```

As far as I can tell from the Solr Documentation ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery ) this is not supported. Is there another way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sortMissingLast` in your schema for `endtime`.

From http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/about-sortMissingLast-and-sortMissingFirst-td473881.html - 
`if sortMissingLast=true then it doesn't matter whether you sort "asc" or "desc", documents that don't have a value for that field will always come last.  if sortMissingLast="false" then the default Lucene sort behavior is used, in which "missing" values are sorted the same as empty strings -- it is the "lowest" possible value, so they come first in asc sorts.`

Once you have that, you can issue this query:
`q=*:*&sort=endtime desc,starttime desc`

(I am not sure why you need to subtract 100 from `starttime`, since sort order will be the same.)